# Consider an election. Candidate A has 60% of the vote and Candidate B has 40% of the vote (binomial distribution). There are no undecided voters.

Tags: probability, statistics, combinations

Candidate A = 60%
Candidate B = 40%

Say that the pollster samples 400 people. What is the probability that, among the first three individuals sampled, exactly two will favor Candidate A?

400 people are sampled, among the first three that are sampled, exactly two favor candidate A. What is the probability that this will happen?

I did try the problem. I did a combination problem (3 chose 2) times .60 raised to the second times .40. I do not know if this is right though. Looking for confirmation.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Answer (score 0):

${3 \choose 2}\,0.6^2\, 0.4 = 0.432$ is a correct application of the binomial distribution

If the $60\%$ and $40\%$ come from the sample of $400$ so $240$ for candidate A and $160$ for candidate B then you have a hypergeometric distribution and the answer would be $ {3 \choose 2}\frac{240 \times 239 \times 160}{400 \times 399 \times 398} \approx 0.4334$

Comment: I think it should be noted that the correct expression is the second one whereas the first is a (rather good) aproximation.